Exercise 4.3.11 of Durrett's Probability: Theory and Examples
I am trying to solve Exercise 4.3.11 from Durrett's book. The question is:

Show that if $P(\lim Z_n/\mu^n = 0)<1$ then it is equal to $\rho = P(Z_n = 0 \text{ for some n}$) where $Z_n$ is the branching process with $Z_0=1$.

I am trying to show that $\{\lim Z_n/\mu^n = 0\} = \{Z_n = 0 \text{ for some n}\}$. I can show that $\{Z_n = 0 \text{ for some n}\} \subset \{\lim Z_n/\mu^n = 0\} $ because if $Z_n = 0$ then the branching process terminates. I can't figure out how to show the other inclusion and I would appreciate any help/hints to solve it.

You cannot prove this  from scratch. It requires a theorem on existence of $\lim Z_n \mu^{n}$ under some conditions. You can refer to Branching Processes by Athreya and Ney.

Suggestion: Let $\pi:=P(\lim_nZ_n/\mu^n=0)$. Show that $\pi=\varphi(\pi)$ and then appeal to Theorem 4.3.12.
